# Field Security Profile not setting checkboxes to read only. crm 2011

Tags: checkbox, dynamics-crm-2011

I have enabled Field security on 2 checkboxes I have on a my form.

Checkboxes:
Security Override (checkbox)
Financial Overide (checkbox)

I have created 2 Field Security Profiles (FSP).

Override Control

This FSP will grant assigned users the ability to read, create, update.

Override Read

This FSP will grant assigned users the ability to read.

When I tested Override Read with an assigned user. I was still able to click and changed the checkboxes. It appears as if crm is ignoring the Override Read FSP.

How can I configure the checkboxes to be read only using Field Security Profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried testing and debugging the issue with the Field Security Profile for a few hours and decided to take a different approach.

I ended up using javascript, when the page loads it will disable the override checkboxes. The checkboxes will only been enabled if the user has a particular security role.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were testing using account that has System Administrator - that would not work because System Administrator will have an access to any fields if I'm not wrong.

UPD in this case please provide screenshots of fields you've made FL-secured, profiles you've created for fields and screenshot of profiles assigned to a user and at the end screenshot of a form with fields.

Comment: I just verified the account I was testing with. It did not have System Administrator. I also checked the System Administrator FSP and the test account has not been assigned.